# Convert custom unity shader to URP

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, cg, urp

Here is the code:

Shader "World Shader"
{
Properties
{
_MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
_TextureScale ("Texture Scale", float) = 1

```
    //[NoScaleOffset] _BumpMap ("Normalmap", 2D) = "bump" {}
}

SubShader 
{
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    LOD 250

    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma surface surf Lambert noforwardadd

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    float _TextureScale;
    //sampler2D _BumpMap;

    struct Input
    {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
        float3 worldPos;
        float3 worldNormal;
    };

    float myFmod(float a, float b)
    {
        float c = frac(abs(a / b)) * abs(b);
        return c;
    }

    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
    {
        float x = IN.worldPos.x * _TextureScale;
        float y = IN.worldPos.y * _TextureScale;
        float z = IN.worldPos.z * _TextureScale;

        float isUp = abs(IN.worldNormal.y);

        float2 offset = float2(myFmod(z + x * (1 - isUp), 0.0625), myFmod(y + x * isUp, 0.0625));

        fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex + offset);

        o.Albedo = c.rgb;
        o.Alpha = 1;
        //o.Normal = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_BumpMap, IN.uv_MainTex));
    }

    ENDCG
}

FallBack "Mobile/Diffuse"
```

}

I switched my unity project to URP and my custom shader stopped working :(
How can I make my custom shader support URP?
How can I convert it?

Comment: Why is this tagged c#?

Comment: why not?
Does it bother anyone? :)

Comment: It has nothing to do with C#. Your issue is with Unity and hlsl. Don't add unnessesary tags. People use them to sort for answers they can help people on. Yes it does bother people.

Comment: You're right, Tanks)

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to convert your shader code into URP, you can try to let Unity convert it for yourself if your shader is simple enough.

Select the materials your shader is applied on.
Edit -> Rendering -> Materials -> Convert the select Built-in Materials to URP.

[Convert material to URP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmmWa.png)

Comment: Yes I know, but
unfortunately it's not working((